# How to use CMake with Emscripten and Conan 2

Tags: cmake, emscripten, conan, conan-2

I am going mad trying to get CMake, Emscripten and Conan 2 playing together.

First thing I tried was just using conan-cmake's develop2 branch, which supports conan 2 but fails with setting unknown compiler versions to the generated profile file. So I decided to try without conan-cmake.

The project is built using `emcmake cmake .. && cmake --build .` from the build directory, after activating Emscripten, sourcing their env script. Everything works as long there is non conan.

The problem is, that conan want's me to use their generated CMake toolchain file. But as soon as I do, the one set by `emcmake` is not used anymore. Setting both manually does not work, too.

There is no documentation from the conan 2 developers regarding Emscripten. Only thing I could find was some Conan 1.x docs. Is Conan 2 totally unusable for anything not yet totally simple or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is not very clear what is the full flow, and where is failing. The ``conan install`` is able to work and install dependencies with your profile? What profile are you using? I'd suggest filing a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues with more details, like the ``conanfile``, the profile, the Conan commands, the full output, the compiler used, etc. The idea would be to have something that the maintainers can reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working the following way:

emscripten.profile

```
[settings]
os=Emscripten
arch=wasm
compiler=clang
compiler.version=15
compiler.libcxx=libc++
build_type=Release

[tool_requires]
emsdk/3.1.50
```

Installing via `conan install`:

```bash
conan install . -pr:b default -pr:h emscripten.profile -s build_type=Release -b missing -of build
```

This outputs a `conan_toolchain.cmake` file into the `build` directory, which sets up CMake for Conan *with* Emscripten.

Running CMake using the generated Toolchain file:

```bash
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

It was pretty unclear to me how to use Emscripten, if Conan already wants you to set a `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`. The Conan documentation for version 1.x includes notes about Emscripten, while the version 2.x documentation does not.